# Draw line in java3d

Tags: java, 3d

I want draw a line between to specify point in java 3d.

how can i do it?

for example for draw a cube we write colorcube.

please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post might help you: [How to draw lines with Java3D [java-tips.org]](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/java3d/how-to-draw-lines-with-java3d.html)

Comment: Here you find a working link: [click here](https://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips-100035/119-java3d/2233-how-to-draw-lines-with-java3d.html).

Answer (score 5):

Use the `LineArray` class. Create an object for it with two vertices( wherever you want them to be) and add this to a Shape3D object.i.e. `new Shape3D(lineArr)`.
For line array:

```
LineArray lineArr=new LineArray(2,LineArray.COORDINATES);
```

then:

```
lineArr.setCoordinate(0,new Point3f());...
```

do the same for the other vertex.

Then add the `shape3D` object to a scene graph or `Branchgroup`.

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The Java code below can generate lines on your 3D screen:

First, build a main class (i.e :tuval1) and second a public class (i.e tuval7) as below.

Also see this link: http://www.itk.ilstu.edu/faculty/javila/ITk356/Java3D/geometry.htm#3.4.2 Point* Classes:

```
import javax.media.j3d.Appearance;

import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;

import javax.media.j3d.GeometryArray;

import javax.media.j3d.LineStripArray;

import javax.media.j3d.Shape3D;

import javax.vecmath.Point3d;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;


public class tuval7 {

    public tuval7(){

     SimpleUniverse u=new SimpleUniverse(); 

    BranchGroup group=new BranchGroup();

    Point3d coords[] = new Point3d[4];

Appearance app=new Appearance();

     coords[0] = new Point3d(-0.5d, -0.2d, 0.1d);
     coords[1] = new Point3d(-0.2d, 0.1d, 0.0d);
     coords[2] = new Point3d(0.2d, -0.3d, 0.1d);
     coords[3] = new Point3d(0.3d, 0.5d, 0.10d);

     int vertexCounts[] = {4};

     LineStripArray lines = new LineStripArray(4,
     GeometryArray.COORDINATES, vertexCounts);

     lines.setCoordinates(0, coords);

    Shape3D shape=new Shape3D(lines , app);

    group.addChild(shape);

    u.addBranchGraph(group);

    u.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();

    }

}

public class tuval1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

new tuval7();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: Guess he wants to show you can use more than two points in the LineArray?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me it draws the x-axis:

```
LineArray lineX = new LineArray(2, LineArray.COORDINATES);
lineX.setCoordinate(0, new Point3f(-100.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
lineX.setCoordinate(1, new Point3f(100.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
scene.addChild(new Shape3D(lineX));
```

a colored line can be drawn like this

```
Appearance appearanceGreen = new Appearance();
ColoringAttributes coloringAttributesGreen = new ColoringAttributes();
coloringAttributesGreen.setColor(new Color3f(Color.green));
appearanceGreen.setColoringAttributes(coloringAttributesGreen);
Shape3D shapeLine = new Shape3D(lineX, appearanceGreen);
scene.addChild(shapeLine);
```