# getAWTGraphicsConfiguration returns null error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, awt, java-3d

I've been tasked with programming a camera in a 3D environment as a part of my CS course.
The purpose is to show how basic camera view transformations are calculated and displayed.
I've been trying to do it in javafx first, but it seems to me too 'high-level' for showing basic calculations.
Now I'm trying to make below java 3d code work on my machine ([copied from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864541/draw-line-in-java3d)), just to see how it works. I split it in two classes as suggested by IDE:

```
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;
import javax.media.j3d.Appearance;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
import javax.media.j3d.GeometryArray;
import javax.media.j3d.LineStripArray;
import javax.media.j3d.Shape3D;
import javax.vecmath.Point3d;

public class tuval7 {
    public tuval7() {

        SimpleUniverse u = new SimpleUniverse();

        BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();

        Point3d coords[] = new Point3d[4];

        Appearance app = new Appearance();

        coords[0] = new Point3d(-0.5d, -0.2d, 0.1d);
        coords[1] = new Point3d(-0.2d, 0.1d, 0.0d);
        coords[2] = new Point3d(0.2d, -0.3d, 0.1d);
        coords[3] = new Point3d(0.3d, 0.5d, 0.10d);

        int vertexCounts[] = {4};

        LineStripArray lines = new LineStripArray(4,
        GeometryArray.COORDINATES, vertexCounts);

        lines.setCoordinates(0, coords);

        Shape3D shape = new Shape3D(lines, app);

        group.addChild(shape);

        u.addBranchGraph(group);

        u.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class tuval1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new tuval7();
    }
}
```

Initially I have installed old Java 3D from Oracle website, but after running into an issue with
[incorrect bitness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57993056/no-idea-to-fix-this-errorunsatisfiedlinkerror-j3dcore-ogl-dll-cant-load) , I have added JARs to my library as per https://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/#netbeans, i.e. j3dcore.jar, j3dutils.jar, vecmath.jar, jogamp-fat.jar .

When run, I'm getting an NPE at a 'SimpleUniverse' line, that I don't know how to solve on my own:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.jogamp.nativewindow.awt.AWTGraphicsConfiguration.getAWTGraphicsConfiguration()" because "<local3>" is null
at javax.media.j3d.JoglPipeline.getGraphicsConfig(JoglPipeline.java:8291)
at javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D.getGraphicsConfig(Canvas3D.java:958)
at javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D.<init>(Canvas3D.java:1028)
at javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D.<init>(Canvas3D.java:990)
at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.Viewer.<init>(Viewer.java:205)
at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.Viewer.<init>(Viewer.java:151)
at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse.<init>(SimpleUniverse.java:249)
at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse.<init>(SimpleUniverse.java:211)
at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse.<init>(SimpleUniverse.java:96)
at tuval7.<init>(tuval7.java:12)
at tuval1.main(tuval1.java:4)
```

Any hint on what `<local3>`is or what is the problem and how to solve that?

I'm using jdk-16.0.1 with NetBeans 12.4 on Windows 10 Pro Version 10.0.19042.

I would be thankful for:

1. A suggestion what Java libraries/extensions would be the simplest to use to program basic 3D camera behaviour. The scenery does not need to be complicated, e.g. just edges (lines) of a few rectangular cuboids would do. The point is to be able to show how camera view changes when rotating camera left/right or up/down or applying basic translations.
2. A solution to the NPE I'm getting, so that at least I could play a bit with these libraries.

Comment: Please try to run a simple example from java3d.org first, something known to work. My tutorial is obviously not to blame.

Comment: @gouessej - I tried the pyramid example from java3D.org and I'm getting the same error when creating 'the universe' ( how humbly it sounds! :D )

Comment: Please contact the current maintainer of Java3D on the official JogAmp forum: https://forum.jogamp.org/java3d-f3728156.html Are you sure that you correctly removed all JARs and native libraries coming from obsolete versions of Java3D to avoid conflicts?

Comment: @gouessej - I have downloaded files from your wordpress [3 jars](https://jogamp.org/deployment/java3d/1.6.2/jogamp-java3d.7z)  and [jogamp-fat.jar](https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.4.0-rc-20210111/archive/jogamp-fat-all.7z) . I'm also using an ant build and attaching these 4 jars by hand to a library and then to that project. I checked the library again and it shows correct pathing.

Comment: Ok. Then, I advise you to contact the maintainer.

Comment: I got the same error because I did select Java 15 as execution environment instead of 1.5.